# Site blurb not yet changed in the back-end?

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-promotion

I just shared a link to GD SE to a LinkedIn Adobe discussion group to try and invite more users.

When I added the link, and the CMS did its thing where it scans the target page and finds the most appropriate description it came back with:

> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for professional graphic designers and non-designers trying to do their own graphic design. It's 100% free, no registration required. Got a question about the site itself?

I actually prefer this to our new blurb for posting a snippet about GD SE on other sites, *but* I had to manually remove the part saying 'Got a question about the site itself?'

I'm just wondering if we're going to be changing this, or keeping it the same. Either way, we need to lose the last sentence.

I don't know if this is already on the to-do list for changes, but if it isn't, here's the reminder.

Answer (score 4):

We're working on this, but it's a little bit of a mystery.

`$Audience` has been updated with the new blurb that you guys picked out. The footer pulls its text out of `$Audience`. It should show the correct blurb. But it doesn't. We told the site to reload itself and will see if that helps.

Otherwise, we'll blame caching. (It's always caching.)

I'll keep this post updated when/if I know more.

Comment: No news, Mr. E, but I'll keep prodding. :)

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter The culprit was caching on our end. We cache  the footer for a year... thanks for staying on top of this, or else we'd be waiting quite a while for it to update on its own. :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the blurb has been changed in all the necessary locations. Not sure where the CMS is pulling that old text from. [Googling for that text](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22This%20is%20a%20collaboratively%20edited%20question%20and%20answer%20site%20for%20professional%20graphic%20designers%20and%20non-designers%20trying%20to%20do%20their%20own%20graphic%20design%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS583US583&oq=%22This%20is%20a%20collaboratively%20edited%20question%20and%20answer%20site%20for%20professional%20graphic%20designers%20and%20non-designers%20trying%20to%20do%20their%20own%20graphic%20design%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.896j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) just returns some garbage (and what looks like a Facebook group that stole the description).

If I had to take a guess in the dark I'd say there's some sort of cache issue. Perhaps this isn't the first time the CMS needed to scrape an appropriate description and just loaded a previous result?

---

Edit: actually, there is one sneaky location that hasn't been updated: the title text for the footer:

```
<a href="http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com" title="professional graphic designers and non-designers trying to do their own graphic design">Graphic Design</a>
```

This doesn't appear to directly give us an answer, but it might be a helpful clue to someone more knowledgable (paging someone from the SE team...)

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter no idea! See my edit though, looks like the old blurb lives on in at least one obscure area, it could be elsewhere too

Comment: Page acknowledged! Will look into it.